# Convert UTC Timestamp to EST SQL DB2

Tags: sql, db2

Convert UTC Timestamp to EST SQL DB2.

I've below query working fine, but I need only date in one column and Timestamp in another column.

Query:

```
SELECT 
    TIMESTAMP(UTC_TIMESTAMP) + CURRENT TIMEZONE AS DATE,
    TIME(UTC_TIMESTAMP) + CURRENT TIMEZONE AS TIMESTAMP,
```

Desired Output:

```
Col_EST_DATE    Col_EST_Time

2020-01-27      14:46:00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Db2 column datatype is already TIMESTAMP then you don't need the extra timestamp function.  Apply the format conversions after the date arithmetic.

Try:

```
select
to_char(date(timestamp(utc_timestamp + current timezone)), 'YYYY-MM-DD') as "Col_EST_DATE",
time(utc_timestamp + current timezone) as "Col_EST_Time",
...
from ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need is the two lines below

```
SELECT 
    DATE(UTC_TIMESTAMP + CURRENT TIMEZONE) AS DATE
,   TIME(UTC_TIMESTAMP + CURRENT TIMEZONE) AS TIMESTAMP
FROM
    TABLE(VALUES(current_timestamp)) T(UTC_TIMESTAMP)
```

which returns

```
DATE      |TIMESTAMP
----------|---------
2020-01-27| 22:14:24
```